# Meaning of "tapped on the shoulder"

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

I am a native French speaker and I do work as a translator in the legal field, and literature (mainly fantasy).

I need an explanation for ‘tapped on the shoulder’:

> As for full-time appointments, the frank stories indicated how small the old-boy network had been. All but one of the senior judges and some veteran district and circuit judges had been **tapped on the shoulder** for their full-time job.

From my point of view, it means that they have been recommended by some people, like when you apply for a job along with several others, but it’s already attributed to someone else (like the son of a director, etc.).

I might be wrong. Would you mind explaining this idiom?

Comment: You tap the shoulder to ask a question: Want a certain job? In the closed circle of WASP males, the judges were invited.

Comment: Nepotism. Ring-fencing.

Comment: See also Headhunting. Typically among an "in" group of people.

Comment: Also used where you think you can identify the best people yourself and mistrust those who might apply for the job (suspecting it would be for the wrong reason).  The real problem is that it excludes people who you might never have considered.

Comment: Doesn't apply in this context, but note that being "tapped on the shoulder" can also have a different meaning: being told that the powers that be have decided that your time is up, and it's time to hand over to someone else. At least in Australia.

Answer (score 25):

> “**tapped** on the shoulder”

In this British (possibly only English - but I doubt it) legal context, it specifically means "**approached** for the purpose of enquiring if the person metaphorically tapped would want to be a judge." In such circumstances the appointment as a judge is virtually certain.

[What Do We Know About This Judge?](https://www.iclr.co.uk/blog/legal-profession/what-do-we-know-about-this-judge/)

> In my opinion, Devlin understates this point. All of the biographies I have read relate to people who were appointed by means of the proverbial ‘tap on the shoulder’. There was no formal appointments process. Each was summoned to go and see the Lord Chancellor. This ‘tête à tête’ was not an interview. The Lord Chancellor had already taken ‘soundings’. The purpose of the meeting was to enable the Lord Chancellor to make an offer. The ‘tap on the shoulder’ process was the complete antithesis of transparency.

Comment: 4.  US
to choose or designate, as for membership in a club Collins Dictionary.

Comment: thank you, this explain why two sentences later, the author is speaking about "Apostolic" succession.

Comment: AU as well.  And not just legal or necessarily OBC/nepotistic as comments to the question suggest.  Someone can get a tap on the shoulder if the tapper knows the prospect is an absolute shoe-in for the position, but is unlikely to be aware of or for some other reason is not expected to apply for the job otherwise.

Answer (score 17):

In the U.S. *tap* alone is used to mean *selected/designated*. In my opinion, it's more common here than "tap on the shoulder."

Edit: in AmE. *to tap* is neutral, without a connotation of favoritism or nepotism, including the use of "tap on the shoulder" in the example below about the "best teachers." I'm not familiar with the nuances of "tap on the shoulder" in BrE. and the OP's example points to a difference.

**tap** (v.)

> SELECT, DESIGNATE
>
> *was **tapped** for police commissioner*
>
> *specifically*: to elect to membership (as in a fraternity) [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tap)

> (usu. **be tapped**) *informal* designate or select (someone) for a
> task or honor, esp. membership in an organization or committee: *he
> had been tapped earlier to serve in Costa Rica.* *New Oxford American
> Dictionary*

---

> I'd voyaged from New York to Panama on the USS Gibbon when my father
> was **tapped** to become military attache to Costa Rica. [Megan
> Edwards; *Road from the Ashes*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Roads_from_the_Ashes/59DsnhlepfUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=was%20tapped%20to%20become&dq=was%20tapped%20to%20become&printsec=frontcover) (1999)

> When Pavia and Harcourt hire her, she promised she would stay with
> them for as long as she remained in private practice. Botwinik asked
> that she stay at least until she was **tapped** to become a Supreme Court
> Justice. [Sylvia Mendoza; *Sonia Sotomayor*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sonia_Sotomayor/TjihDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=was%20tapped%20to%20become&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> But Liscouski did say the feds are looking to build a leadership team,
> and he specifically wants to **tap** someone with industry knowledge and
> business expertise to lead the still vaguely defined effort. [Patricia
> Keefe; "Security Disconnect" in *Computerworld*, July 21, 2003](https://books.google.com/books?id=yKgDSqp_DbQC&pg=PA20&dq=%22to%20tap%20someone%22%20means&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSn7_-h7f1AhVDmXIEHTYwDHkQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22to%20tap%20someone%22%20means&f=false)

> Sell knew Ernie had experience, so he **tapped** him for the job. “One
> of the reasons I brought him in,” Sell says, “was to establish
> controls where there were none before.” But Ernie had little respect
> for controls. [Joseph Wells; *Corporate Fraud Handbook*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Corporate_Fraud_Handbook/PyGZDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=tapped%20him%20to%20the%20position&pg=PA132&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

---

> Being **tapped on the shoulder** [and invited into administration] is
> problematic. I think it pulls the best teachers out of the classroom.
> I think the best teachers are always **tapped on the shoulder** to
> become an administrator. [K. Hunter-Quartz et al.; *Making a
> Difference*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Making_a_Difference/8wJZCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22tapped%20on%20the%20shoulder%20to%20become%22&pg=PT48&printsec=frontcover) (2016)

Comment: I (BrE) remember being very confused by the first panel of this old xkcd comic (AmE) which uses *tap* in this sense: https://xkcd.com/398/. I eventually looked it up but didn't realise this sense of *tap* derives from *tap on the shoulder*, I thought it was just an unusual Americanism.

Comment: I can't remember seeing "tapped on the shoulder" used with this sense before answering this question. I don't think the origin comes immediately to mind for an American.

Comment: @DjinTonic It is most certainly a sports reference though. I would assume baseball, from the wiki page on pitchers: *"When making a pitching change a manager will come out to the mound. He will then call in a pitcher by the tap of the arm which the next pitcher throws with. "*

Comment: @StianYttervik The expression, even meaning selection, predates baseball, and managers tap their left or right arm, not a shoulder.

Comment: I (AmE) do think "tapped on the shoulder" has more of a "corrupt old boys' club" connotation than just "tapped," though.

Comment: @MissMonicaE That's very possible--I'm not familiar with its connotations because, as mentioned, I don't come across it.

Comment: As a Canadian, I'm convinced it has to do with extracting the metaphorical sap from the newly hired person via a tap.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany If you asked Canadian/US speakers the origin of *tapping a person for a position*, I wouldn't be surprised if you get a 50-50 distribution of a "tapping a shoulder" vs. "tapping a resource".

Comment: I would go so far as to suggest that the authors of the original quote may have mixed their metaphors. To tap on the shoulder is to get the attention of someone who's not aware of you; it's not a good metaphor for "privately contacted", and certainly not if the contact was solicited or expected. But "tapped" doesn't convey the back-room secrecy that's at play, it really just means to make use of a resource. So I think this is a bit of word-association mashup.

Answer (score 9):

While I agree with other answers, I also would like to add this:
In certain fraternities, honor societies, and organizations which serve[d] as power networks, [s]election to a higher level is done by a secret process.  This may be by a secret ballot in which members may be able to vote for more than one candidate if they feel multiple candidates are qualified, or by some other process.

As part of a ceremony, a member of the higher level describes for all the benefits & obligations of participating in that higher-level network, then requires all to close and cover their eyes, and then literally taps the selected individual(s) on their shoulder to communicate to them and nobody else that they have been selected for this higher-level position.  The tapped individual(s) then know that they are supposed to go to a particular place at a particular time, or otherwise mentally and physically prepare for the recently-described next steps in the process.

Answer (score 2):

I love language. Although not formally trained nor specifically instructed the following is pure whimsy from years of reading and some very bizarre trivial knowledge.

Tapping on the shoulder is a selection, not a nomination. Its more of "Hey your up."

I suspect that this has its etymology in Britain with the ceremony for knighthood, when one is literally tapped on the shoulders with the ceremonial blade to serve their lord.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Some (semi-)secret societies actually employ a physical tap on the shoulder to nominate an initiate into the society, or to signify an increase in rank or position.  As an example, the Boy Scouts Order of the Arrow tap-out ceremony, seen here from 1944: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaVTZOYynXA

Answer (score 0):

Super simple.
Imagine you’re standing at the bus stop.  And I - a total stranger standing behind you - want to ask you something. So I gently tap you on the shoulder with my finger - tap, tap. What would you do? You’d turn around to see who touched your shoulder, right? I got your attention.

That’s what tapping someone on their shoulder means: to get their attention.

Comment: I think you're ignoring the specific judicial context provided in the question.

Comment: You are right. It seems Urban Dictionary has defined “tapped on the shoulder” as being fired from the job (laid off). So in the context given, it means that all except a few were laid off from their full time jobs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Urban Dictionary has defined “tapped on the shoulder” as being fired from the job (laid off). So in the context given, it means that all except a few were laid off from their full time jobs.